# Ubuntu enable user to save files in dir

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, users

I want the user 'kevin' to be able to ftp/sftp read/write/execute files in the /home/kevin/public_html dir...

This shouldn't be hard, I'm just a beginner.  Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure kevin is the owner of the directory, you can use the chown command like this:

```
chown -R kevin.kevin public_html
```

assuming you are already in /home/kevin

also you may need to change the read/write/execute permissions like this:

```
chmod -R 644 public_html
```

you may want to use 755 for files that need to be executable.

For more info on octal file permissions, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

You can find out other info my typing `man chown` or `man chmod`

There may be other things you have to do depending on which FTP daemon you are using. For example, if you are using the ProFTPd, check out this HOWTO: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79588

Comment: +1 You beat me to the punch!

Comment: You want to ensure the directories retain the execute bit.  This is required in order to chdir into the directory.  So a chmod 644 -R on public_html will actually deny access to 'kevin'.